# How can encoding be specified while creating an avro file based on a json data?

Tags: python, avro, avro-tools

How can encoding be specified while creating an avro file based on a json data?

The avro created using Apache avro tools (jar) is not readable using Python code.

Comment: Can you post your code and the avro file to show the error? If the file was encoded with a codec, that would be included in the file itself and the reader should use that codec when reading.

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 17 invalid start byte